# Unable to get Click action on RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

> I am using RecyclerView in BottomSheet.The data is fetched successfuly but unable to get click action on the RecyclerView items. This is my `BottomSheetAdapter` code :

```
public class BottomSheetAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BottomSheetAdapter.ViewHolder> {
List<UserDetailsModel> userDetailsModelList;
Context context;
private Onitemclicklistenersuggestion listener;

public BottomSheetAdapter(List<UserDetailsModel> userDetailsModelList, Context context) {
    this.userDetailsModelList = userDetailsModelList;
    this.context = context;

}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.bottom_sheet_recycler_items, parent, false);
    return new BottomSheetAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    UserDetailsModel model = userDetailsModelList.get(position);
    holder.firstNameLabel.setText(model.getFirst_name().trim());


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return userDetailsModelList.size();
}


class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    TextView firstNameLabel;
   
    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        firstNameLabel = itemView.findViewById(R.id.firstNameLabel);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (listener != null) {
            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                listener.clicktoupdate(position);
            }

        }
    }
}

public interface Onitemclicklistenersuggestion {
    void clicktoupdate(int poistion);

}

public void setOnitemclicklistener(Onitemclicklistenersuggestion mlistener) {
    listener = mlistener;
}
```

}

> This is my `BottomSheetDialog` code :

```
    public class BottomSheetDialog extends BottomSheetDialogFragment 
implements BottomSheetAdapter.Onitemclicklistenersuggestion {

  bottomSheetAdapter = new BottomSheetAdapter(userDetailsModelList, getActivity());
  bottomSheetRecycler.setAdapter(bottomSheetAdapter);
  bottomSheetRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
  bottomSheetAdapter.setOnitemclicklistener(new BottomSheetAdapter.Onitemclicklistenersuggestion() {
      @Override
      public void clicktoupdate(int poistion) {
          Log.e("Pos", "Pos");
      }
  });
  bottomSheetAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}

  @Override
    public void clicktoupdate(int poistion) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), ""+poistion, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

> But after clicking the RecyclerView items neither the Log or the Toast message shows up. Please help me fix it. Thanks in Millions.

Comment: What value getting in `int position = getAdapterPosition();`  on click of Button?

Comment: I added a   Log.e("POSITION", ""+position); after this line, but its not getting executed even if i click on the items in recyclerview

Comment: use `firstNameLabel.setOnClickListener(this);` and check if getting Toast or log on click of firstNameLabel.

Comment: Yes, i am getting the Log statement now,

Comment: But, why not showing on Item Click

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `onClick` logic inside your ViewHolder class.
So something like,

```java
class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView firstNameLabel;
   
    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               // show a toast msg or whatever action you need...
            }
        });

        firstNameLabel = itemView.findViewById(R.id.firstNameLabel);
    }
}
```

Comment: I wanted to access the click via the BottomSheetDialog class and not from the adpater

Comment: @Zibran It is unclear from your second code snippet how you are declaring `bottomSheetAdapter` and `bottomSheetRecycler` variables. Please show all of your code.